# ScalaTest - Create Dynamic tests based on input / expected output (forAll)

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

Consider the following `Table`:

```scala
object MyTestsFactory {
  val testCases = Table(
    ("testName", "input", "output"),
    ("test-1", "1", 1),
    ("test-2", "2", 2),
    ("test-3", "3", 3), 
  )
}
```

and the following tests case:

```scala
class MySpec extends FunSuite {
  test("Test Parsing Function") {
    forAll(MyTestsFactory.testCases) { (testName: String, input: String, output: Int) =>
     input.toInt shouldBe output
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that it creates one test, and runs all the inputs on the specific test.

Is that possible to create test for each row on the `Table` via `forAll`? is there maybe other solution? (`C#` solution attached)

For example something as follows:

```scala
class MySpec extends FunSuite {
  test("Test Parsing Function") {
    forAll(MyTestsFactory.testCases) { (testName: String, input: String, output: Int) =>
      test(s"Testing $testName") {
        input.toInt shouldBe output
      }
      input.toIntOption match {
        case Some(value) => value shouldBe output
        case None => fail(s"Parsing error on $testName")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**which does not compile**

```scala
TestRegistrationClosedException was thrown during property evaluation. (ConsentStringSpec.scala:12)
  Message: A test clause may not appear inside another test clause.
  Location: (ConsentStringSpec.scala:13)
  Occurred at table row 0 (zero based, not counting headings), which had values (
    testName = test-1,
    input = 1,
    output = 1
  )
```

Is it possible in some way?

---

Example on C#: **(Looking for something similar in Scala)**

```cs
public class MySpec
    {
        [TestCase( "1", 1, TestName = "test-1")]
        [TestCase("2", 2, TestName = "test-2")]
        [TestCase("3", 3, TestName = "test-3")]

        public void TestingParsing(string input, int output)
        {
           Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(input), output);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why you want a test for each case?

Comment: To see in clear way which test is passed and which test is fails, i want to create factory to the test-cases with input/expected outputs and check that with generic code. there something similar on c#, i re-edit the post

Comment: Uhm AFAIK `forAll` should produce a detailed error message about which test failed. In any case, you should be clear that what you want is just a good error message.

Comment: Maybe `forAll` is not the right solution, please check the `c#` solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code, is that you are trying to nest your tests. It cannot be nested. Please just try to flip the `test` and `forall` order, for example:

```
class MySpec extends FunSuite with Matchers {
  forAll(MyTestsFactory.testCases) {
    x => {
      test("Test Parsing Function" + x._1) {
        x._2.toInt shouldBe x._3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you get 3 tests:

[image]

Comment: Working great, there a bug in the IDE that you must run the whole class/spec to make it run, for example run a specific test in the tests hierarchy will not run, for example: ```mySpec { "first hirearchy" - { forAll { ... "testName" in { .. } } } }``` will not work by clicking on run tests for `first hirearchy` - Thanks Tomer!