# Dynamicaly Created Tests sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm trying to dynamically run some basic tests in the following way (this is a pseudo code of my test, my actual tests are a bit more complicated):

```
class ExampleTest extends AnyWordSpec {
  
  def runTests() = {
    for( n <- 1 until 10){
      testNumber(n)
    }
  }
  
  def testNumber(n: Int) = {
    "testNumber" when {
      s"gets the number ${n}" should {
        "fail if the number is different than 0" {
          assert(n == 0)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  runTests()
  
}
```

When I try to run my tests in IntelliJ all the tests run as expected. But when using `sbt tests` It says that all my tests passed even though non of my tests actually got executed (I get the message "1 tests suite executed. 0 tests where executed").
How can I fix this? Is there any other simple way to dynamically create tests in scala?)

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972284/scalatest-on-sbt-not-running-any-tests

Comment: You may want to use Scalatest `forall` feature. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041007/scalatest-create-dynamic-tests-based-on-input-expected-output-forall for instance.

Comment: Unclear what's going on. I created a small project with just this tests, using Java 11, Scala 2.13.6, Sbt 1.4.2 and pulling in Scalatest 3.2.10 and `sbt test` successfully runs the tests. It's probably just a typo, but if by any chance you have some custom build key called `tests` that could be the reason for the behavior you are observing (the command you want to invoke is `sbt test`).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a comment, I'm not sure what the problem with `sbt` is.

Another way you can try to create test dynamically is using property-based testing.

One possible way is using table-driven property checks, as in the following example (which you can see in action [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/dz95eeSKSzy30BnG8aT5JA/3)):

```
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpec
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks._

class ExampleTest extends AnyWordSpec {

  private val values = Table("n", (1 to 10): _*)

  "testNumber" when {
    forAll(values) { n =>
      s"gets the number ${n}" should {
        "fail if the number is different than 0" in {
          assert(n == 0)
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Of course all these tests are going to fail. ;-)

Links to the ScalaTest documentation about the topic:

- [property-based testing](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/property_based_testing)
- [table-driven property checks](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks)
- [generator-driven property checks](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/generator_driven_property_checks) (especially useful to test a lot of cases within the same case)